# Why isn't the prop reactive in the dynamic component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have a dynamic component being injected in the slot of another one and I pass the props object to it. But when I update the data (an array) which has been assosiated with the prop (`dataT: this.tableData`), that prop isn't being updated inside the component.

It seems like I have a deal with two different objects but the array was passed by the reference, wasn't it?

This is the main component

```
    <template>
       <Button @click="addWindows"></Button>
       <Window v-for="window in windows" :key="window.id">
          <component :is="window.name" v-bind="window.props" @onDeleteRow="handleDeleteRow"></component>    
       </Window>
    </template>


    <script>
        export default{
           data(){
              return{
                 windows:[],
                 tableData:[
                    {
                       id: '0',
                       name: 'dog'
                    },
                    {
                       id: '1',
                       name: 'cow'
                    },
                    {
                       id: '2',
                       name: 'cat'
                    }
                 ]
              }
           },  
           methods:{
              addWindows(){
                 this.windows = [
                 {
                    id: 0,
                    name: 'Component1',
                    props: {
                       dataT: this.tableData
                    }
                 }, 
                 {
                    id: 1,
                    name: 'Component2',
                    props: {}
                 }];
              },
              handleDeleteRow(id){
                 this.tableData = this.tableData.filter(r => r.id != id);
              }
           }
        }
    </script>
```

I expect updating `dataT` prop in `Component1` when I modify `this.tableData` in the main component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Original answer based on an earlier version of the question

If you make `windows` a computed property it can depend on `tableData`:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      tableData: [
        {
          id: '0',
          name: 'dog'
        },
        {
          id: '1',
          name: 'cow'
        },
        {
          id: '2',
          name: 'cat'
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    windows () {
      return [
        {
          id: 0,
          name: 'Component1',
          props: {
            dataT: this.tableData
          }
        }, {
          id: 1,
          name: 'Component2',
          props: {}
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If you can't make all of it a computed property, e.g. because you need to be able to modify it, then keep it as `data` and just use the computed property to create the array needed in your template. In that case the computed property would just be merging together different parts of the data into the correct form.

In your original code, the line `dataT: this.tableData` won't work because `this.tableData` doesn't exist yet, it'll just be `undefined`. There's no lazy evaluation here, it needs to resolve to the correct object at the point it hits that line.

Even if it was able to get access to the correct object it wouldn't help because in `handleDeleteRow` you're reassigning `tableData` to point to a different object. Passing 'by reference' has nothing to do with the name you use to identify the object, it refers to a reference in memory.

Incidentally, `v-on` also supports an object syntax, just like `v-bind`, so you could make `onDeleteRow` optional in a similar fashion.

#### Update based on the edited question

When you write this in `addWindows`:

```js
props: {
    dataT: this.tableData
}
```

This will assign the **current** value of `this.tableData` to `dataT`. That current value will be an array and as arrays are reference types any modifications made to that array will apply no matter what identifier is used to reference it.

However, this line...

```js
this.tableData = this.tableData.filter(r => r.id != id);
```

... does not modify that array. Instead it assigns a totally new array to `this.tableData`. This will have no effect on the array referenced by `dataT`, which is unchanged.

There are several ways you could approach solving this, including using a computed property. However, a property getter might provide a convenient sleight-of-hand:

```js
addWindows () {
  const vm = this;

  this.windows = [
    {
      id: 0,
      name: 'Component1',
      props: {
        get dataT () {
          return vm.tableData
        }
      }
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Component2',
      props: {}
    }
  ];
}
```

This will always evaluate to the current value of `tableData`. Vue's reactivity should be fine with this extra indirection, it just sees it as equivalent to accessing `tableData` directly.

Comment: Yes, I know, actually `windows` is empty array initially, I fill it by clicking on the button, I just decided to simplify the code. I'll update the code with your suggestion to not mislead others but it doesn't solve the main problem with the binding unfortunately

Comment: Have updated the code. Do you have any ideas how to solve the problem?

Comment: @DenisLolik I have updated my answer to reflect the new question

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**

The issue is with your binding. Use the following:

```html
<component 
    :is="window.name"
    :dataT="window.props.dataT"
    @onDeleteRow="handleDeleteRow">
</component>
```

**Explanation**

the `v-bind` attribute specifies what prop is bound to what value (or reference). In your case, you didn't specify what values you're binding to what props, thus the component props weren't bound as expected.

Comment: Thanks, but what if the ```Component2`` that is supposed to be injected as well has absolutely different props. I don't want to list all of the props because part of them doesn't refer to whatever component is used.

Comment: In such cases, you can pass a `props` props (do you get what I mean?).
The child component will destruct the props and validate via custom validator.

Comment: @Aviad The OP is just using the object form of `v-bind`. Writing `v-bind="obj"` is perfectly valid, see https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind

Comment: @Aviad I get what you mean, but maybe there's another more elegant approach